# How to make Clang changle the rules of two-phase lookup?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I want this to compile without an error. Just want it to wait until the instantiation

```
template<class T>
struct A : public T{
   void f(){ foo(); }
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: I assume you are aware that this is not standard-compliant C++, right? That said, clang does have an MSVC compatibility mode (MSVC did not properly implement two-phase lookup until quite recently) that does what you want. But I don't get why you would want to do this (other than for MSVC compatibility reasons).

Comment: Why don't you tell us what your real problem is? The one that isn't "I want to change the rules of C++" :)

Comment: Is `foo` a member function of a class you pass as a template parameter? If so, you should mention that in the question.

Comment: I would suggest a read at [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As I told, I just want it to compile. The reason being that I have some(a lot) of code that was written in this manner, so it would be much easier to have the compiler let this compile and not go and manually add lots of `using` statements

Answer (score 3):

You might change your code to:

```
template<class T>
struct A : public T{
   void f(){ this->foo(); } // or T::foo();
};

int main() {}
```

making `foo` type dependent to fix your code.

Comment: Alternatively, `T::foo();`.

Answer (score 1):

Two-phase lookup rules is defined by the c++ standard and/or by compiler.
Changing rules aren't possible like you can't change laws. You need to tell us what the real problem is.